# Remove sensitive data from Git commit with tree filter and sed on macOS

Tags: git, macos, sed, zsh

I tried reading through multiple posts about `sed` and how to remove keys from a file that's already committed. I'm trying this

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter \
"sed -i '' 's/my_sensitive_data/<your-api-key>/' ./app/src/main/java/com/demo/Test.kt"
```

I keep getting `sed ./app/src/main/java/com/demo/Test.kt: No such file or directory`. But if I take that same command

`sed -i '' 's/my_sensitive_data/<your-api-key>/' ./app/src/main/java/com/demo/Test.kt`

From the directory I'm running the `git filter-branch` command in, the `sed` command does replace it appropriately.

I'm running macOS catalina and using ZSH. What might I be doing wrong here?

Comment: The man page for git filter-branch says this for the `--tree-filter` argument: "(...) The argument is evaluated in shell **with the working directory set to the root of the checked out tree**." Does this match what you are expecting? I don't know what your directory structure looks like, so it is hard to tell from here whether this could be the problem.

Comment: @prosoitos yes it is run in the root directory where `.git` is.

Comment: But is it a commit that's old? Because if it is a recent revision and no one has seen it, you can amend the revision.

Comment: @eftshift0 yes it's not actually an issue. i just wanted to see how that would actually work in practice.

Comment: Does every commit have the file?

Comment: @krisz no not every commit. but the most recent commit does have it. when i try the "git rm....." removes the whole file and that works. But was just wondering if there was smething wrong with my command in macOS. i also installed gsed and tried that, but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `git filter-branch`, Git runs the filter on *every commit*.<sup>1</sup>  That is, the tree-filter:

- checks out the commit (in a temporary directory);
- runs the specified command (in that temporary directory); and
- builds the replacement commit from whatever that command leaves behind.

The filter-branch command repeats this for every commit that is to be copied.  (That's what filter-branch does: it *copies* commits.  The originals continue to exist.)

Some of your commits have the file; the `sed` command would work on those commits.  Some of your commits *lack* the file and the `sed` command in this case fails.  The failure, which `git filter-branch` sees as a non-zero exit status from your filtering command(s), causes `git filter-branch` itself to stop and not do the filtering you wanted.

The solution is to avoid running this `sed` command entirely when the file does not exist.  There are two ways to do that (see footnote 1) but the *simplest* is to modify your command to *check* first.  Instead of:

```
sed -i '' 's/my_sensitive_data/<your-api-key>/' ./app/src/main/java/com/demo/Test.kt
```

you would use:

```
if [ -f app/src/main/java/com/demo/Test.kt ]; then
    sed -i '' 's/my_sensitive_data/<your-api-key>/' app/src/main/java/com/demo/Test.kt
fi
```

Note: if and when you squish this up into a single line, it requires at least one more semicolon.  I left it out (and took out the `./` as well, since it's redundant) to make the lines fit better for posting purposes.

---

<sup>1</sup>Technically, it runs the filter only on *the commits you tell it to*, which can be fewer commits than *every* commit.  The commits that will be visited are those that are named explicitly or implicitly via *positive references*, excluding those named explicitly or implicitly via *negative references*.  There is a fair bit of jargon in that single sentence and it is worth unpacking it a bit:

- A *positive reference* is one not preceded by a negation, nor used in any of the various special syntactic methods that negate a reference.  Simple examples of this include `feature` (a branch name), `v2.1` (a tag name), and `a1234567` (an abbreviated commit hash).
- A *negative reference* is one preceded by a negation, or used in syntax that negates: `^feature`, `^v2.1`, `^a1234567`.  For a simple example of a syntax that negates, consider `master..feature`: this is exactly equivalent to writing `feature ^master`.
- The phrase *explicitly or implicitly* refers to the fact that Git is *walking the commit graph*.  For a proper tutorial on what this means, see [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/).

All positive references mentioned on the command line cause Git to walk the commit graph, marking commits to be copied.  All negative references cause Git to walk the graph, un-marking commits.  If you view the process as "mark first, then unmark" you get the right result: only the *marked* commits get copied-and-filtered.  If you view it as "unmark first", then the "mark after" phase must respect all earlier "unmarkings".  (Git actually does it in a complicated interleaved fashion, so that it always gets the right result, but does so faster than a naive two-pass algorithm.)

Those positive references that are *branch names* cause the name to be remembered.  Git then arranges all the marked commits into an appropriate order—one topologically sorted as needed for the copying process—and begins the copying.  As it copies, it builds a map from old hash ID to new hash ID.  At the end of the copying process, for each of these saved branch names, Git forces the name to point to the new hash ID instead of the old one, and the filtering is now complete.

Hence, if there's a simple (or complicated!) range expression that lets Git enumerate *only* the commits you *need* to copy-and-filter, you can use that, rather than a test in your filter.  For instance, suppose the sensitive data is introduced specifically in commit `badf00d`, whose parent is `cafedad`: all *good* commits are therefore reachable from `cafedad` and all *bad* commits are in the commits starting with `badf00d` and continuing up to the tip of `master`.

Some commits *before* `cafedad`, and possibly `cafedad` itself, *lack* the `Test.kt` file and hence the `sed` will fail on them.  In that case:

```
git filter-branch <filter-specifiers> -- cafedad..master
```

will do the trick, because this limits the copying-and-filtering to only those commits that (a) *have the file* and (b) *require the edit*.